# Select Data From Closed Excel Sheet Using ADO

Tags: excel, ado

I have a workbook called "SomeFile.xlsx"  I need to connect to this sheet and extract a range of data from a worksheet.  I am trying to connect using ADO with no success.  I have the following code:

```
Sub ExtractData()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim PathName As String
Dim PathRange As String

    PathRange = "SELECT * FROM [AddConvert$D4:D10];"
    PathName = "C:\path\myFile.xlsx"
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 "
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & PathName & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With  'Works fine up to here
    Set rs = cnn.Execute(PathRange)  'Dies here

End Sub
```

Everything works as far as I can tell.  I put a watch on `cnn` and a break on the last line.  `cnn` looks good.  HOwever, it keeps saying it can't find the AddConvert worksheet and get the data.  I don't understand why it can't find it or what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Excel 12.0 for .xlsx files. Example:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
    Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

from [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: Sorry, I caught that and changed it, and it still gives the error.  :(

Comment: Oh!  It was a typo!!  THANKS!

Comment: You forgot the "Xml" ;) ? Glad you got it sorted.